# How can I grow i and j before Exit for?

Tags: excel, vba

Here's my code:

```
 Sub Horizon()
Dim i As Double, j As Double, x As Double, y As Double
Sheets("B").Range("C3:G10000").ClearContents
x = InputBox("Number of rows in A")
y = InputBox("Number of rows in B")
For i = 3 To x
    For j = 3 To y
     If Sheets("B").Cells(j, 1) = Sheets("A").Cells(i, 1) And Sheets("B").Cells(j, 2) >= Sheets("A").Cells(i, 2) And Sheets("B").Cells(j, 2) <= Sheets("A").Cells(i, 3) Then
     Sheets("B").Cells(j, 3) = Sheets("A").Cells(i, 4)
     Sheets("B").Cells(j, 4) = Sheets("A").Cells(i, 5)
     Sheets("B").Cells(j, 5) = Sheets("A").Cells(i, 6)
     Sheets("B").Cells(j, 6) = Sheets("A").Cells(i, 7)
     Sheets("B").Cells(j, 7) = Sheets("A").Cells(i, 8)
     Else

     Exit For
     End If
     Next j
     Next i
End Sub
```

how can I `Next i` and `Next j` before that `exit for`?...is there a way?
I tried in this way `i=i+1` but it didn't work.If I'm writing `next i` and `next j` before that `exit for` it gives me an error.

Comment: This loop hurts my eyes.

Comment: Why do you need to `Exit For` ?  Are you trying to exit the outer loop?

Comment: @Jens: Agreed O.o  however, what he's asking should work - might not be the best way to code it - but it *should* work (as shown in my tests below). something else is going on he's not telling us ;)

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This likely will make the problem obvious and you will be able to answer on your own.

Comment: @Valentin, what are you trying to do with your code?

Comment: Are you trying to exit the second for loop with "j" or do you want to exit all for loops? If you want to exit the inside loop i think you can simply delete "Else" and "Exit For". No?

Comment: It appears Valentin wants to increment I and/or J before the exit for. If I'm correct, For-Loops in VBA won't take notice of whatever changes you've made. For example, say `i` is currently at 5 and you add 3 to it, in the next iteration it will be 6, not 9. The alternative would a `Do-While` loop.

Answer (score -1):

Did this quick test: shows "8" in the output .. so not sure why you say the i=i+1 doesn't work ?  it "should". ;)

```
  Sub test()
    For i = 1 To 10
       If i = 5 Then Exit For
    Next i
    i = i + 3
    MsgBox (i)
  End Sub
```

[edit] ahh, just noticed, you said "before" the exit for ... hmm, that's more interesting ... [/edit]

[/edit2] or not ... just tried it .. works for me

```
  Sub test()
    For i = 1 To 10
       If i = 5 Then
         i = i + 1
         Exit For
       End If
    Next i
    MsgBox (i)
  End Sub
```

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Too large for comment, and without the code snippets, it's senseless.  Needed the space and formatting to express the point properly.

Comment: My response here is a fully workable, complete test case, attempting to show the OP that doing a i=i+1 does in fact work. It is not a sloppy answer, it not incomplete. It is on topic, and is not "dangerously incorrect".

Comment: Your "tests" don't at all attempt to address the user's issue, which appears to be an awkward if-statement. Obviously loops and incrementing works, OP's question is "how can i Next i and Next j before that exit for?" The user needs to restructure their program to achieve this, not be shown that they can increment using `i=i+1`